# How to store data about individual users without having separate csv files for each of them?

Tags: java, eclipse, file, csv

I'm not sure about how to store data about individual users in a golf program that I'm designing (each user needs to have their previous holes etc tracked and logged) in Java

I was wondering if there is a way to store this data without needing to create an individual file for each user?

Any help is much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Of course, a single CSV file could do the trick here.

Comment: Any further insight? @khriskooper

Comment: Just write the data in a single file? Add the username in the data so you can distinguish whose data it is.

Comment: Ohh, but the only issue I'm having with that is that I need to let each user see only their scores etc, and then surely sorting it would be really ineffficent?

Comment: Depends on how many thousands of users you're expecting. I also wouldn't bother with sorting, since you can just filter out the relevant information from the file at startup.

Comment: Is the file CSV format a requirement? If yes, which rows (per user?) and columns there are? Otherwise, see my answer below.

Comment: Do you need to store data in files in order to exchange them with some other application/system, or them files will be used just internally by your program?

Comment: The CSV format isn't a requirement and as @Kayaman said I'm a bit too inexperienced to get the JSON working,

Comment: @LittleSanti I don't need them for another application, they are for internal program use only

Answer (score 1):

You could store this as JSON instead, E.G:

```
{
"Arnold Palmer" : {
    "handicap" : "2", 
    "history" : {
        "1" : {
            "courseName" : "St Andrews",
            "holeNumber" : "1",
            "score" : "2"
        }, 
        "2" : {
            "courseName" : "St Andrews",
            "holeNumber" : "2",
            "score" : "3"
        }
        ... etc
    }
}, 
"Tiger Woods" : {
    "handicap" : "4", 
    "history" : {
        "1" : {
            "courseName" : "Pebble Beach",
            "holeNumber" : "1",
            "score" : "4"
        }, 
        "2" : {
            "courseName" : "Pebble Beach",
            "holeNumber" : "2",
            "score" : "6"
        }
        ... etc
    }
}
```

Then, just parse it when the program starts up and extract the info you need for that user (there are libraries you can use for this). I would suggest that JSON is a more suitable data format for your needs as you need to store dynamic, graph-like data. CSV files are excellent for more simple data sets.

I would still think it better to keep to a seperate file per user though as it will save you having to read through one huge file to find the data you need. Depends how many users you will have though.

Also, if you need to persist data between users, have a shared file for this (e.g. highscores).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the files to be exported to another program/system, you can stop caring about its format and start thinking about creating a class hierarchy for your model, which eventually will rely upon **Java object serialization**:

Writing objects to a file:

```
    MyObject obj1=...;
    MyObject obj2=...;

    try (ObjectOutputStream output=new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file)))
    {
        output.writeObject(obj1);
        output.writeObject(obj2);
    }
```

Reading objects from a file:

```
    try (ObjectInputStream input=new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(file)))
    {
        MyObject obj=(MyObject)input.readObject();
    }
```

You just need to ensure that your class (MyObject in the upper example) implements `java.io.Serializable`, as well as every class involved in its definition (member variables and its subsequent definitions).

You can calso serialize/parse a **collection** of objects, as long as you chose a serializable implementation of Collection (for example `java.util.ArrayList`).

Answer (score -3):

In Java the easiest way to store key-value pairs are **[properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) files**, e. g.:

- Write:

  ```
  Properties prop = new Properties();
  prop.setProperty("user1.prevHole", "foo");
  prop.store(new FileOutputStream("golf.properties"), null);
  ```
- Read:

  ```
  Properties prop = new Properties();
  prop.load(new FileInputStream("golf.properties"));
  String prevHole = prop.getProperty("user1.prevHole");
  ```

See *[Java Properties file examples](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/)*

Comment: The discussion has been about CSV, not key-value pairs.

Comment: @Kayaman I did not understand CSV as a requirement (see my question comment above): _[...] each user needs to have their previous holes etc [...] I was wondering if there is a way to store this data without needing to create an individual file for each user?_

Comment: @howlger CSV isn't a requirement, however, I think that properties seem to be the easiest way for me to do this, however, is there any way in which I could edit these outside of the program?

Comment: Using `Properties` for user data storage is a pretty bad idea.

Comment: @TheHacker _.properties_ files are text files and can be edited with a text editor: [see Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.properties)

Comment: @Kayaman Why? Because they are not encrypted? Or for performance or scalability reasons?

Comment: @howlger Because as you said, they're key value pairs. They're meant for configuration, not for user data. CSV isn't exactly elegant, but property files would be an inane choice. JSON would work, but I'm pretty sure that the asker is too inexperienced to get that working. That's why I commented about combining the CSVs (since he apparently has that working for separate files).